# a question about likelihood equation

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $V_1,...,V_n$ be i.i.d. the d-variate random vectors, each with a density $f(V,\beta_0)$ that satisfies the Regularity Conditions. Let $L(\beta)$ be the log-likelihood function of the observations $V_1,...,V_n$ and let $Q(\beta)$ be the penalized likelihood function $L(\beta)-n\Sigma_{j=1}^dp_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_j|)$, where $p_{\lambda_n}(|·|)=\lambda_np(|·|)$ is a penalty function and $\lambda_n>0$ is a tuning parameter.
Prove: if max$\{|p''_{\lambda_n}(\beta_{j0})|:\beta_{j0}\ne0\}\rightarrow0$,then there exists a local maximizer $\hat{\beta}$ of $Q(\beta)$ such that $\lVert\hat{\beta}-\beta_0\rVert=O_p(n^{-1/2}+a_n)$,where $a_n=max\{|p'_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_{j0}|)|:\beta_{j0}\ne0\}.$

I tried Taylor's formula, but I have no idea about the relation between $\hat{\beta}$ and $\beta_0$. When $\hat{\beta}$ is consistent for $\beta_0$, it seems easier to solve, but can that be proved?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960   Also, please use MathJax

Comment: Oh,I haven't used that before.I will try and edit the question.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here.  At first glance you have a problem "setup", and then the post ends.

Comment: I reedit the question.